# How to animate background color of each item of RecyclerView when data changed?

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview

This gif shows the iOS equivalent of what I want to do with Android.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEuV2.gif

Those values change would be triggered by data transfer, so I'm not able to use `onClick` callbacks for doing this.